# Как писать в stderr без отметок времени?

Tags: golang, логирование

<sup>(Перевод
[вопроса с ENSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29721449/1892060).)</sup>

Как в *Go* писать в `stderr`?  `log.Printf`
будет писать со временем, а мне нужно без него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>(Перевод
[ответа с ENSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29721449/1892060).)</sup>

Во-первых, для логгирования без отметок времени можно создать новый
логгер с нулевыми флагами:

```golang
var l = log.New(os.Stderr, "", 0)
l.Println("hello world")
```

Во-вторых, можно и просто писать напрямую в `os.Stderr`:

```golang
n, err = os.Stderr.WriteString("hello world")
```

Или, если нужен форматированный вывод:

```golang
n, err = fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "number: %d", i)`
```